# BeanFactoryPostProcessor modify the actual bean definition instead of the instance?

Tags: java, spring

Here is brief what BeanFactoryPostProcessor does

> A BeanFactoryPostProcessor lets you modify the actual bean definition
>   instead of the instance as it's created.Spring IoC container will
>   allow BeanFactoryPostProcessors to read the configuration metadata and
>   potentially change it before the container has actually instantiated
>   any bean. PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is the example of
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessors to externalize some property values into
>   another separate file in Java Properties format

What i understand from above is BeanFactoryPostProcessor modies the bean definition at the start of application context(ie while applocation load).
But i did not get does it changes class definition physically in the file or in memory.

i am usingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in my project. To verify it , once application got started , i went to class path and opend the class file in decompiler
whether propert {test.property} got replaced with actual value or not. Its not. So does spring modifies the class definition in  memory ?

Comment: I think class definition and bean definition are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BeanFactoryPostProcessor will not change the physical class definition. And in most of the applications in production, the user who runs the application will not even have access to 'write' to the files. All modifications happen once the classes are loaded. So when you need a bean instance, Spring will load the bean definition (but won't instantiate 'any' instance), apply the bean factory post processor that's registered and then create an instance (and then apply the bean post processor, which is different from bean factory post processor) and then only returns the bean.

Comment: so it means that beanfactorypostprocessor change bean definition in memory not in physical file ?

Answer (score 0):

a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` can change/add **BeanDefinition**

a BeanDefinition is just a metadata describing a bean :

- The name of the bean
- The class to instanciate
- Properties to inject
- Dependencies
- ...

It's the equivalent in xml of a `<bean id=".." class=".."/>` tag